# Display Success message on the same page when submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using `Html.Beginform` in view page and get the parameters using `FormCollection` to the controller i want to return the Success message on the same `ViewPage` as a result.i'm using following code,

```
public string InsertDetails(FormCollection collection)
{     
     string result = "Record Inserted Successfully!";
     return result; 
}
```

It shows the success message on the new page.How can i resolve this? what i have to return to get the Success message on the same page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally, I'd pop the result string into the ViewBag.

```
public ActionResult InsertDetails(FormCollection collection)
{
         //DO LOGIC TO INSERT DETAILS
         ViewBag.result = "Record Inserted Successfully!";
         return View(); 
}
```

Then on the web page:

```
<p>@ViewBag.result</p>
```

Comment: As a note, ensure you return the correct view. Noting that this Controller Action is not prefaced with `[HttpPost]` i am guessing it is not the method the view was originally called from

Answer (score 12):

I have following Options.

**1. Use Ajax Begin Form with AjaxOptions like below**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" }, new
    AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "alert('Success');" //This will execute once the Ajax call is finished.

    }, null))
{
    <input type="submit" name="nameSubmit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**2. Use JQuery to Manually Setup the XHR Request**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" });",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({param : Value})
})
.done(function () { alert('Success');}) //This will execute when you request is completed.
.fail(function () { })
```

**My Suggestions**

There are following disadvantages while using the FormCollection

**Point - 1**

In case `FormCollection` is being used...It will be mandatory to `Type Cast` the `Primitive Type` Values un-necessarily because while getting the entry of specific Index of the `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`, value being returned is of type `String`. This situation will not come in case of Strongly Typed `View-Models`.

**Issue - 2**

When you submit the form and goes to `Post` Action Method,  and `View-Model` as Parameter exists in the Action method, you have the provision to send back the Posted Values to you `View`. Otherwise, write the code again to send back via `TempData/ViewData/ViewBag`

[image]

**Point - 3**

We have Data Annotations that can be implemented in `View Model` or `Custom Validations`.

[image]

*ASP.Net MVC simplifies model validatons using Data Annotation. Data Annotations are attributes thyat are applied over properties. We can create custom validation Attribute by inheriting the built-in Validation Attribute class.*

**Point - 4**

Example you have the following **HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="textBox1" value="harsha" customAttr1 = "MyValue" />
```

***Question*** : How can we access the value of customAttr1 from the above eg from inside the controller

**Answer** : When a form get posted only the name and value of elements are posted back to the server. *You can also use Hidden Fields to post the Attributes to Post Action method*.

**Alternatives** : Use a bit of jQuery to get the custom attribute values, and post that along with the form values to action method

Another option is to rather put what you got in your custom attributes in hidden controls

That's the reason, I would always prefer to use `View-Models`

Comment: very intriguing comic characters you have

Answer (score 0):

we can do it on Form inside view

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "Showmessage" }))

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(TestViewModel model)
    {
         return Json(new {isok=true, message="Your Message" });          
    }

    function Showmessage(data)
    {
      $('#Element').html('Successfully Submitted');
    }
```